Viterbi Algorithm Implementation to get the most Probable Path
The following is the python implementation of the hidden markov models using the viterbi algorithm. The code consists of taking an example of a sample graph with nodes and edges. Then we take points at the certain offset of the graph. But now I want to know the most probable path. The code snippet is as follows:
Here the array coordinates represent the nodes of the graph and the array separate points correspond to the offset points. The emission and the transition probabilities have been calculated and have been used in the viterbi function.
Note : The array pi comprises of the initial probabilities and have been manually put by me. The values of beta and sigma_z have been calculated prior itself.
import numpy as np
import math

def calculate_transition_probs(coordinates, separate_points, beta):
    num_nodes = len(coordinates)
    transition_probs = np.zeros((num_nodes, num_nodes))
    
    for i in range(num_nodes):
        for j in range(num_nodes):
            route_dist = np.linalg.norm(np.array(separate_points[1]) - np.array(separate_points[0]), ord=2)
            great_circle_dist = np.linalg.norm(np.array(coordinates[j]) - np.array(coordinates[i]), ord=2)
            d_ij = abs(great_circle_dist - route_dist)
            transition_probs[i, j] = 1 / beta * math.exp(-d_ij / beta)
        
        transition_probs[i] /= np.sum(transition_probs[i])
    
    return transition_probs

def calculate_emission_probs(coordinates, separate_points, sigma_z):
    num_nodes = len(coordinates)
    num_offsets = len(separate_points)
    emission_probs = np.zeros((num_nodes, num_offsets))
    
    for j in range(num_nodes):
        for i in range(num_offsets):
            dif = np.linalg.norm(np.array(separate_points[i]) - np.array(coordinates[j]))
            exponent = -0.5 * ((dif) / sigma_z) ** 2
            p = 1 / (math.sqrt(2 * math.pi) * sigma_z) * math.exp(exponent)
            emission_probs[j, i] = p
    
    return emission_probs

def viterbi(pi, transition_probs, emission_probs):
    T = emission_probs.shape[1]  # Number of observations
    N = transition_probs.shape[0]  # Number of states
    
    # Initialize Viterbi table and backpointer
    viterbi_table = np.zeros((N, T))
    backpointer = np.zeros((N, T), dtype=int)
    
    # Initialize the first column of the Viterbi table
    viterbi_table[:, 0] = pi * emission_probs[:, 0]
    
    # Fill in the rest of the Viterbi table
    for t in range(1, T):
        for j in range(N):
            # Compute the probabilities for transitioning to state j at time t
            probabilities = viterbi_table[:, t-1] * transition_probs[:, j] * emission_probs[j, t]
            # Find the maximum probability and corresponding state at time t
            viterbi_table[j, t] = np.max(probabilities)
            backpointer[j, t] = np.argmax(probabilities)
    
    # Backtrack to find the best path (sequence of state indices)
    best_path = []
    # Find the index of the state with the highest probability at the last time step
    final_state = np.argmax(viterbi_table[:, T-1])
    best_path.append(final_state)
    
    # Backtrack from the last time step to the first time step
    for t in range(T-1, 0, -1):
        final_state = backpointer[final_state, t]
        best_path.append(final_state)
    
    # Reverse the best path to get the correct sequence of states
    best_path.reverse()
    
    return best_path

# Given parameters and data
beta = 0.865617024533378
sigma_z = 2.593490783789292

coordinates = [(0,0), (0,0.5), (0,1), (0,1.5), (0,2), (0.2,2), (0.5,2), (0.7,2), (1,2)]
separate_points = [(-0.2,0.5), (-0.2,1.5), (0.2,1.8), (0.7,2.2)]

transition_probs = calculate_transition_probs(coordinates, separate_points, beta)
emission_probs = calculate_emission_probs(coordinates, separate_points, sigma_z)

print("Transition Probability Matrix:")
print(transition_probs)
print()

print("Emission Probability Matrix:")
print(emission_probs)
print()

pi = np.array([0.25, 0.7, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714])

# Perform Viterbi decoding to find the best path
best_path_indices = viterbi(pi, transition_probs, emission_probs)
best_path_coordinates = [coordinates[idx] for idx in best_path_indices]

print("Most likely hidden state sequence (indices):", best_path_indices)
print("Most likely hidden state sequence (coordinates):", best_path_coordinates)

The output that I got for the above code is :

Transition Probability Matrix:
[[0.081359   0.14496525 0.25829871 0.14496525 0.081359   0.08042682
  0.07577457 0.0709121  0.06193931]
 [0.1139089  0.06392921 0.1139089  0.20296258 0.1139089  0.11217538
  0.10371676 0.0952015  0.08028789]
 [0.1496549  0.08399097 0.04713834 0.08399097 0.1496549  0.14626991
  0.13057839 0.11598034 0.09274128]
 [0.09319984 0.16606323 0.09319984 0.05230664 0.09319984 0.0974405
  0.11839247 0.14130249 0.14489516]
 [0.05814007 0.10359383 0.18458322 0.10359383 0.05814007 0.0732519
  0.10359383 0.13052004 0.18458322]
 [0.06302526 0.11187101 0.19783359 0.1187687  0.08032721 0.06375575
  0.09016424 0.11359982 0.16065441]
 [0.06282366 0.10943467 0.18685397 0.15267662 0.12018869 0.09539383
  0.06745362 0.08498624 0.12018869]
 [0.05725337 0.0978207  0.16162047 0.17745134 0.14746466 0.11704278
  0.08276174 0.06568804 0.09289691]
 [0.04573691 0.07544957 0.11819656 0.16641907 0.19073162 0.15138379
  0.1070445  0.08496128 0.0600767 ]]

Emission Probability Matrix:
[[0.29850026 0.25726285 0.23901001 0.20522689]
 [0.2785173  0.25856418 0.24563629 0.21728224]
 [0.25929227 0.25929227 0.25188301 0.22953246]
 [0.24086951 0.25945715 0.25772711 0.24194623]
 [0.22328322 0.25907394 0.26314997 0.25449287]
 [0.22106134 0.2564959  0.26364859 0.25879417]
 [0.21772029 0.25261931 0.26433804 0.26532236]
 [0.21548807 0.25002927 0.26475819 0.26972447]
 [0.21213354 0.24613704 0.26532834 0.27640108]]

Most likely hidden state sequence (indices): [1, 3, 1, 3]
Most likely hidden state sequence (coordinates): [(0, 0.5), (0, 1.5), (0, 0.5), (0, 1.5)]

However, the expected output for the sequence should be [1, 3, 5, 7]
We got the correct expected output by applying a brute force method which is as follows:
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

coordinates = [(0,0),(0,0.5),(0,1),(0,1.5),(0,2),(0.2,2),(0.5, 2),(0.7,2),(1,2)]
separate_points = [(-0.2,0.5),(-0.2,1.5), (0.2,1.8), (0.7, 2.2)]

all_combinations = list(itertools.combinations(coordinates, 4))
pi = np.array([0.25, 0.7, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714, 0.00714])

valid_sequences = []
for sequence in all_combinations:
    if len(set(sequence)) == 4:  
        valid_sequences.append(sequence)

Prob = []
index = []
for seq in valid_sequences:
    seq_as_list = [list(coord) for coord in seq]
    id = np.array([coordinates.index(coord) for coord in seq]) 
    index.append(id)
Index = np.vstack(index)

for i in range(126):
    # print(Index[i])
    r0 = Index[i][0]
    # print(r0)
    P = 1
    ps = pi[r0] * normalized_emission_matrix[r0][0]
    if i== 74:
        ps = 0
    else:
        for j in range(1,4):
            rA = Index[i][j-1]
            cA = Index[i][j]
            P *= normalized_transition_matrix[rA][cA] * normalized_emission_matrix[cA][j]
            # print(P)
        ps *= P
        Prob.append(ps) 
Prob = np.array(Prob).reshape(125, 1)
# print(Prob)
m = max(Prob)
print(m)
ind = np.argmax(Prob)
print(ind)
print(index[76])


@ Ashwin Sasikumar Since you know the expected output it means you have a reference algorithm. What are the key differences?

We had applied a brute force method to get the correct output

@SudoKoach I have added the brute force code which gave us the correct output as [1, 3, 5, 7]
